# Qual a melhor forma(inclui frameworks) de trabalhar com arquivos JSON? Usando Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Gente, tenho que listar alguns dados baseados em um json e também usar algumas estruturas de controle com propriedades desse arquivo, então, qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com eles? se possivel explique como passar de um arquivo .json(sem escrever todo ele no código) para um objeto javascript.

Answer (score 1):

### JS Puro

Para *browsers* modernos, basta usar o `JSON.parse`

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

alert(obj.count);
```

Veja os browsers suportados:

> http://caniuse.com/json

### jQuery

Para jQuery:

```
$.getJSON( "caminho_do_arquivo/arquivo.json", function( data ) {
    // use 'data' aqui
});
```

### Solução *fallback*

Você pode usar bibliotecas externaso, como esta, por exemplo:

> https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js